# Largest of all land, or largest of land?

Tags: grammar

Here are some sentences. I want to know whether or not these sentences are correct:

> The elephant is the largest of land animals.
>
> The elephant is the largest of **all** land animals.

Comment: Your title and your examples do not match. The title only includes "of" in one of them. Can you please clarify what your question is?

Comment: Largest of land, largest of all land animals

Comment: They mean the same thing. To some people the word *all* is redundant. To other people it seems to sound wrong without it. Perhaps they don't read enough. In my mind I can hear an elementary teacher saying the second one and a National Geographic narrator saying the first.

Answer (score 1):

With "of", only the second is correct:

> The elephant is the largest of all land animals.

If you leave out "of" the first can work (if animal is singular):

> The elephant is the largest land animal.

Here's an example of this usage on a [website](http://a-z-animals.com/blog/the-biggest-land-animal-on-earth/):

> The African Elephant is the largest land animal on Earth

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, only the the second one is correct:

> The elephant is the largest of all land animals

This is because "land animals" is a group, so you need "all" to denote that you are pertaining to a group of something (in this case animals).

However, both sentences are phrased awkwardly, and it would be more practical to use comparison with "any other"

> The elephant is larger than any other land animal

You would not use "any" because the elephant is a land animal, and using any would mean it can be larger than itself, which is not possible

You could also just keep it simple and just use "is" instead of using "of"

> The elephant is the largest land animal

This works since you're implying that "The elephant" is a land animal, which it is.

Comment: I politely disagree.